# Best way to find the number of distinct element in a submatrix using python

Tags: python, matrix

Given a matrix and a range, what is the best way to find the number of distinct elements in the sub-matrix? I tried:

```
for i in l[a-1:c]: #a is the start row and c is the end row
            s.extend(set(i[b-1:d]))  #b is the start column and d is the end column
     print len(set(s))
```

E.g)

The given matrix:

```
1 2 3
3 2 1
5 4 6
```

Given:

```
a = 1, b= 1, c = 2, d = 3
```

The answer should be 3, as there are only 3 distinct elements in the sub matrix 1,1 to 2,3

Is there any other pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: With `numpy` this would be quite simple since there would be multidimensional slicing like `arr[a:b, c:d]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all the slicing you need without the use of a for-loop (see below). I've used the `Counter` module to count the number of unique items in the remaining sub-matrix.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

mat=[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[5,4,6]]
mat = np.matrix(mat)

submat = mat[a-1:c,b-1:d] # extract the sub matrix desired

flattened = np.array(submat.flatten()).flatten() #flatten it for use in counter

print Counter(flattened) # prints the counts of each unique item

len_unique = len(Counter(flattened)) # the total number of unique items.
```

Comment: `submat = mat[a-1:c][::,b-1:d] # extract the sub matrix desired` with `numpy` you could write something like `mat[a:b, c:d]`

Comment: Oops, fair point - I've edited my answer to reflect this @starrify

Comment: and this shows me an error at a.flatten() `int object has no attribute flatten`

Comment: @AswinMurugesh `a.flatten()` shall be `submat.flatten()`

Comment: Sorry, bug in what I had written. `a` should have been `submat`; I've fixed it above. Hopefully that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable([t[b-1:d] for t in l[a-1:c]]))

# len(...)  this should get the length
```

Comment: What about the column limit?